# A condition after LookUpPolicy to only continue to getJwt if there is a cache miss ? How to do this in Apigee

Tags: proxy, apigee

A condition after LookUpPolicy to only continue to getJwt  if there is a cache miss ? How to do this in Apigee

--if there's a cache miss on lookup, then proceed, else return the jwt

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common use case of caching policy in apigee. You can use lookup cache and populate cache in below mentioned order.

```
<Step>
    <Name>lookupJwtCache</Name>
</Step>
<Step>
    <Condition>lookupcache.lookupJwtCache.cachehit = false</Condition>
    <Name>getJwt</Name>
</Step>
<Step>
    <Condition>lookupcache.lookupJwtCache.cachehit = false</Condition>
    <Name>populateJwtCache</Name>
</Step>
```

In step 1, lookupJwtCache will do a cache look up to check if the jwt exists.

- If it exists then step 2 and step 3 will be skipped because there is a
  condition added to check for cache hit.
- If it does not exist, meaning the cache has expired. Then you will generate the token again with getJwt(step 2) and populate the cache(step 3) so that it can be accessed on the next lookup.